# datagrid selected index gives troubles

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a datagrid that I fill with data from a database.
When I click on a row, I call the GotFocus method and try to make a button visible if certain requirements are met.

```
private void dtgVerkoopsdocumenten_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataItem row = (DataItem)dtgVerkoopsdocumenten.SelectedItems[0];
    if (row.soort2 == "Factuur")
    {
        btnBoeking.IsHitTestVisible = true;
        btnBoeking.Opacity = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        btnBoeking.IsHitTestVisible = false;
        btnBoeking.Opacity = 0.5;
    }
}
```

This gives me an error.

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
```

Now when I call the code but from a button click it does it how it's supposed to work.

```
private void tester_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataItem row = (DataItem)dtgVerkoopsdocumenten.SelectedItems[0];
    test.Content = row.soort2;
    if (row.soort2 == "Factuur")
    {
        btnBoeking.IsHitTestVisible = true;
        btnBoeking.Opacity = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        btnBoeking.IsHitTestVisible = false;
        btnBoeking.Opacity = 0.5;
    }
}
```

Why is this?

Comment: Looks like `dtgVerkoopsdocumenten.SelectedItems[0];` must be the problem. Did you check if you really have selected items?

Comment: I know that gives the problem, and I do have items selected. I just don't get why it gives an error when I execute the code via the gotfocus method but not when I execute it via a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you use DataGrid SelectedIndexChanged event?

Wyy use GotFocus that doesnt tell you if user even made a selection to start with,

```
DataItem row = (DataItem)dtgVerkoopsdocumenten.SelectedItems[0];
```

Called from gotfocus will fail as you have nothing selected besides having no error check in place to check if selection,

If you use Selection changed events you know the user has made selection changes there are a number of events for selection

Comment: Thanks. Don't know why I didn't thought about this before. One remark though. In wpf you have to use the selectionchanged event, as selectedindexchanged doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Because dtgVerkoopsdocumenten.SelectedItems are empty and `GotFocus` event raise before `SelectedItemChanged` event so we are not sure the `dtgVerkoopsdocumenten.SelectedItems` have any item or not.
You can check `dtgVerkoopsdocumenten.SelectedItems` before do anything.

```
    if (dtgVerkoopsdocumenten.SelectedItems != null && 
        dtgVerkoopsdocumenten.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    { 
      DataItem row = (DataItem)dtgVerkoopsdocumenten.SelectedItems[0];
      ...
    }
```

Comment: the problem seems to be also that the selected index is not the index it's supposed to be. Like the second row gets index 0, first one index 1

Answer (score 0):

before access selected items by index you need to check selected item count is grater than zero condition.